# High memory usage by Stack Overflow web pages in Chrome

Tags: discussion, meta, performance

Each Stack Overflow webpage consumes like ***300-350 MB*** of memory which is pretty high. For the sake of proof, checkout this screenshot:

> [image].

And this screenshot of current Stack Overflow Meta post:

> [image]

Is there a memory leak? I think this must be addressed.

#### System Info:

- **OS**: Mac OS X ElCaptain 10.11.3
- **Browser**: Chrome Canary Version 51.0.2685.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: I think it's Chrome and your extensions that are using high memory usage, just like on Gmail. (I use Chrome too, it's "only" 30MB on MSO)

Comment: @AndrewT. Chrome Task Manager shows different entries for Browser Extensions. I did not capture that in my screenshots. So I doubt if the memory usage by chrome extension is the case. I will update the question with system info.

Comment: What I meant is, since it shows the memory usage of the *tab*, it could include extensions that were injected to the page, resulting in more memory usage than what it supposed to be. Try comparing with no extensions/incognito tab.

Comment: I shouted out 'Chrome' before I opened this question:(

Comment: HA! Firefox is 12MiB @AndrewT.

Comment: The only case that I would say is someone else fault is if you are being MitM and your ISP injects ads to SO pages.

Answer (score 3):

For this page and the homepage I get less than 100MB so I'm going to go with what everyone else is saying and assume it's most likely because of your browser extensions.

In Chrome extensions do have their own memory amount show per background process but anything that they have running in the page's context should be adding to the tab's memory amount in the Chrome task manager. You can see this easily by checking the difference between the amount of ram the page takes with and without incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks @X O. I tried in incognito mode but it takes around 120 MB which is still high according to me. 30-40 MB is acceptable but more than that I consider high.

Answer (score 2):

This is the memory usage for my "heaviest" open tabs:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't server-side.

Have a look at your browser extensions. They may add to a tab's memory usage, if they add something to the page.

Also, you may want to consider ***scanning your system for malware***. The high memory usage could be an indication of malicious scripts being injected into your loaded pages.

Comment: There is obviously malware loaded - it's called Chrome:(

Comment: Surprisingly, AdBlocker addon takes ~150MB which is not a tab and purely runs in background. Anyway, Good to know that this is only my machine's problem