# High memory usage by Stack Overflow web pages due to googlesyndication

Tags: bug, meta, performance

Each Stack Overflow webpage consumes like 300-350 MB of memory which is pretty high. For the sake of proof, checkout this screenshot when typing about:memory in firefox.

[image: googlesyndication takes 260 MB for each Stack Overflow page]

It seems that it comes from an external frame from googlesyndication. Nevertheless, the users impacted are the ones of the website.

(tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-15/html/container.html).

I decided to post a new question as advised in [High memory usage by Stack Overflow web pages in Chrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319423/high-memory-usage-by-stack-overflow-web-pages-in-chrome)

Comment: Possibly related: [Why do stale Stack Overflow tabs use so many resources?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362294/why-do-stale-stack-overflow-tabs-use-so-many-resources)

Comment: version of Firefox? I'm unable to repro those results. The googlesyndication safeframe never gets above 5MB for me.

Comment: FWIW, I opened a tab in Chrome with a Google-served ad on it about the time you posted this - currently chewing up > 700MB. Looks like Google's ad code has a leak.

Comment: Add it to the list of reasons to run an adblocker.

Comment: for some more egregious examples (not all ads and not SO, but the same general thing) http://idlewords.com/talks/website_obesity.htm#fixes (language advisory for some parts)

Comment: @Jeutnarg: For a counter-example, see [mother****ingwebsite.com](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/). Language advisory for _all_ the parts, for comic effect.

Comment: IE11 is currently using 445 MB - and all unwanted connections (AKA adverts) are blocked in the hosts file

Comment: I'm in China and I don't have any memory usage issue on Stack Overflow tabs.

Comment: Indeed, it was not the case this morning. I'll try to keep pages open all day long as I usualy do to check if it is a memory leak or just a epiphenomenon.

Comment: Alternative revenue streams https://www.wired.com/story/cryptojacking-cryptocurrency-mining-browser/

Comment: @TemporalWolf So you think Google is crypto mining?

Comment: Keeping the page opened for 24 hours and googlesyndication taking up to 783 Mo / 970.47 MB (79.48%) -- window-objects > 877.18 MB (71.84%) -- top(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches, id=12884901928) > 802.46 MB (65.72%) -- active > 783.30 MB (64.15%) -- window(https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-15/html/container.html) >  782.89 MB (64.12%) -- js-compartment(https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-15/html/container.html)

Comment: Hopefully this will get fixed now that subframes are displayed in Chrome task manager separately That's what led me here - 400+MB for a stupid syndication frame. (

Comment: I am seeing unbearably high CPU usage while loading forbes.com articles. But I noticed blocking all Javascript brings CPU down to normal levels. Can someone help me, how do I identify & block only specific JS sources that are causing high CPU and not all sites, since I tried blocking forbes.com on the list but it didn't work.